# github actions - build fail after change yarn.lock

Tags: github-actions, yarnpkg

Im using github action flow like below

[image]

but build fail when after my dependabot update `yarn.lock`

build error message is below

```
Run yarn build
Usage Error: The project in /home/runner/work/na-lab-client/na-lab-client/package.json doesn't seem to have been installed - running an install there might help

$ yarn run [--inspect] [--inspect-brk] [-T,--top-level] [-B,--binaries-only] <scriptName> ...
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

**Q1. why this error occured?**

**Q2. How can I solve this error?**

---

I tried not using dependency cached, then it works

> job `Build` run it self install own dependency

also build success where deploy environment

---

my `ci.yml` code is below

```yaml
name: CI

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]
  push:
    branches: [main]

env:
  CACHED_DEPENDENCY_PATHS: ${{ github.workspace }}/.yarn/unplugged
  CACHED_BUILD_PATHS: ${{ github.workspace }}/.next
  BUILD_CACHE_KEY: ${{ github.sha }}
  DEFAULT_NODE_VERSION: '16'

jobs:
  job_install_dependencies:
    name: Install Dependencies
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 15
    steps:
      - name: Check out current commit (${{ github.sha }})
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ env.DEFAULT_NODE_VERSION }}

      - name: Compute dependency cache key
        id: compute_lockfile_hash
        run: echo "::set-output name=hash::${{ hashFiles('yarn.lock') }}"

      - name: Check dependency cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        id: cache_dependencies
        with:
          path: ${{ env.CACHED_DEPENDENCY_PATHS }}
          key: ${{ steps.compute_lockfile_hash.outputs.hash }}

      - name: Install dependencies
        if: steps.cache_dependencies.outputs.cache-hit == ''
        run: yarn install --immutable
    outputs:
      dependency_cache_key: ${{ steps.compute_lockfile_hash.outputs.hash }}

  job_build:
    name: Build
    needs: [job_install_dependencies]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 15
    steps:
      - name: Check out current commit (${{ github.sha }})
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ env.DEFAULT_NODE_VERSION }}

      - name: Check dependency cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ${{ env.CACHED_DEPENDENCY_PATHS }}
          key: ${{ needs.job_install_dependencies.outputs.dependency_cache_key }}

      - name: Check build cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        id: cache_built_packages
        with:
          path: ${{ env.CACHED_BUILD_PATHS }}
          key: ${{ env.BUILD_CACHE_KEY }}

      - name: Build
        if: steps.cache_built_packages.outputs.cache-hit == ''
        run: yarn build

    outputs:
      dependency_cache_key: ${{ needs.job_install_dependencies.outputs.dependency_cache_key }}

  job_codechecks:
    if: github.event_name != 'push'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Run codechecks
    needs: [job_install_dependencies]

    steps:
      - name: Check out current commit (${{ github.sha }})
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ env.DEFAULT_NODE_VERSION }}

      - name: Check dependency cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ${{ env.CACHED_DEPENDENCY_PATHS }}
          key: ${{ needs.job_install_dependencies.outputs.dependency_cache_key }}

      - name: Run codechecks
        run: yarn codechecks
        env:
          CC_SECRET: ${{ secrets.CC_SECRET }}

  job_continuous_integration:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Check test & lint
    needs: [job_install_dependencies]

    steps:
      - name: Check out current commit (${{ github.sha }})
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ env.DEFAULT_NODE_VERSION }}

      - name: Check dependency cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ${{ env.CACHED_DEPENDENCY_PATHS }}
          key: ${{ needs.job_install_dependencies.outputs.dependency_cache_key }}

      - name: Check Lint
        if: github.event_name != 'push'
        run: yarn lint

      - name: Check Stylelint
        if: github.event_name != 'push'
        run: yarn lint:style

      - name: Check Unit Test
        if: github.event_name != 'push'
        run: yarn test

  job_codecov_test_coverage:
    name: Set codecov unit test coverage
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [job_install_dependencies]
    steps:
      - name: Check out current commit (${{ github.sha }})
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ env.DEFAULT_NODE_VERSION }}

      - name: Check dependency cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ${{ env.CACHED_DEPENDENCY_PATHS }}
          key: ${{ needs.job_install_dependencies.outputs.dependency_cache_key }}

      - name: Create Unit Test Coverage
        run: yarn test:coverage

      - name: Set unit test coverage
        uses: codecov/codecov-action@v3
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.CODECOV_TOKEN }}
          fail_ci_if_error: true

  job_e2e_test:
    timeout-minutes: 60
    name: Check e2e test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [job_install_dependencies]
    steps:
      - name: Check out current commit (${{ github.sha }})
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ env.DEFAULT_NODE_VERSION }}

      - name: Check dependency cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ${{ env.CACHED_DEPENDENCY_PATHS }}
          key: ${{ needs.job_install_dependencies.outputs.dependency_cache_key }}

      - name: Install Playwright Browsers
        run: yarn playwright install --with-deps

      - name: Run Playwright tests
        run: yarn test:e2e

      - name: Report playwright tests
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        if: always()
        with:
          name: playwright-report
          path: playwright-report/
          retention-days: 30

  job_nextjs_bundle_analysis:
    name: Nextjs bundle analysis
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [job_build]
    steps:
      - name: Check out current commit (${{ github.sha }})
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ env.DEFAULT_NODE_VERSION }}

      - name: Check dependency cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ${{ env.CACHED_DEPENDENCY_PATHS }}
          key: ${{ needs.job_build.outputs.dependency_cache_key }}

      - name: Check build cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ${{ env.CACHED_BUILD_PATHS }}
          key: ${{ env.BUILD_CACHE_KEY }}

      - name: Analyze bundle sizes
        uses: transferwise/actions-next-bundle-analyzer@master
        with:
          workflow-id: ci.yml
          base-branch: main
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: https://github.com/depromeet/na-lab-client
you can check more detail of the code

Comment: Why are these checks `if: steps.cache_dependencies.outputs.cache-hit == ''` not being compared against `true` or `false` in your workflow?

Comment: See https://github.com/depromeet/na-lab-client/actions/runs/5201826540/workflow#L40 and https://github.com/depromeet/na-lab-client/actions/runs/5201826540/workflow#L73.

Comment: Every job starts with an empty working directory. If you have build in a previous job, and you want to continue on that job, you have to have a build artifact that is the subject to continue with (e.g. a tarball). If that artifact was only per some caching earlier, change that to a real build artifact. That should then close the build gap and make things much more explicit. Consider to have immutable artifacts.

Comment: Azeem hakre / thanks to comment!

It fixed with appending .pnp.cjs and .pnp.loader.mjs!
> it deleted after dependabot pr merged

Answer (score 0):

It fixed with appending .pnp.cjs and .pnp.loader.mjs!

> it deleted after dependabot pr merged